# html type = file

Tags: php, html, file

With a html type=file, how can I tell if file was uploaded.
Is there something in the $_POST values to indicate so?

```
<form action="program" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="text" name="textline" size="30">
<input type="file" name="datafile">
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Comment: what server-side language are you using?

Comment: See the PHP manual on handling file uploads: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Answer (score 1):

Check the $_FILES array:

```
if ($_FILES['datafile']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    // file was uploaded
}
```

'error' will match one of the predefined upload constants, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php for all the possible values.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_FILES);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`$_FILES` variable](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) contains information regarding file uploads, including original filename, mime type, temporary file name, error code and size of the uploaded file.